# Regularity of local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring. It is well known that $R$ is regular iff $\operatorname{pd}(R/\mathfrak{m}) < \infty$ (i.e. $R/\mathfrak{m}$ has finite projective dimension).

Assume that $\dim R > 0$. Is $R$ regular, if $\operatorname{pd}(R/\mathfrak{m}^2)< \infty$?

Comment: If $R$ is regular, *every* $R$-module has finite projective dimension.

Comment: I know it. But i ask: Is it true that if $pd(R/mathfrak{m}^2)<\infty$, then $R$ is regular? provided $\dim R > 0$.



Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Levin–Vasconcelos](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=230715) ([journal link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-25/issue-2/Homological-dimensions-and-Macaulay-rings/pjm/1102986272.full)): for $R$ a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, the existence of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ such that $\mathfrak{m}M$ has finite projective dimension and $\mathfrak{m}M\neq 0$ implies R is regular.

Applied to $M=\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}$, this implies that if any nonzero power of the maximal ideal has finite projective dimension, then $R$ is regular.

Answer (score 8):

If $R$ has positive dimension, then for any $t\ge 1$, the ideal $I=\mathfrak m^t$ is a so called Burch ideal (as defined by Dao,  Kobayashi, Takahashi; [Burch ideals and Burch rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02310v3) )  i.e. $\mathfrak m(I:\mathfrak m)\ne \mathfrak mI$.

It is a Theorem of Burch that if $I$ is a Burch ideal and $R/I$ has finite projective dimension, then $R$ is regular.